# How to hit breakpoint only when some specific unit test is run?

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, junit

I am trying to solve the issue where one of `unit tests` fails **only** when I run **all** the tests in the project.

Thus I would like to come inside some *common code* only when my failing test is executed. I was trying to find out how to achieve it in `Intellij IDEA` because there is a feature of condition breakpoints, but for now I fail because don't understand how I can write this type of condition plus it seems that other possibilities don't really allow this.

***Is it possible?***

Comment: You want to hit a break-point inside some test, when you run that test only?? in more specific are you asking how to run a single selected test without running all at once?? I am in difficult to get you.

Comment: No, I want to hit breakpoint outside specific unittest, but inside some common code when I run all tests and this specific unittest is executed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put a breakpoint in the test case that fails (in the image its line 28). Put another break point(in the image its line 42) in the common-code and make that as a conditional one that is disabled till the break point in the test case is hit. To get this window, right click the breakpoint (sometimes you'll have to disable and then re-enable the suspend checkbox).

Hope it helps!

[image: conditional break point]

Comment: Yes, it seems that this is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of an IDEA feature which lets you do this, however there are some manual steps that you can take to do this type of debugging:

1. Add a breakpoint to the first line of the unit test that is failing.
2. When this breakpoint hits, add another breakpoint in the common class you're interested in.

Alternatively, you can do this in a more automated, repeatable way by making some minor modifications to your unit test code.

1. Add a public static boolean field to your Unit test class which is set to false by default.
2. set this to true in the first line of the failing test
3. Use this field in your test condition. e.g. if your unit test was "ThingTest" and your field "footest" - you're condition will be "ThingTest.footest == true"
4. Set it to false at the end of your failing test (if you want the follow on tests to run normally)

Comment: First option is clear and yes, I tried it, but because the test fails randomly and I have tried it so many times, became tired and decided to check if it is possible with another way. Boolean variable sounds interesting.

Answer (score 1):

How about declaring a boolean value, set it to false by default, and only set it to true when you test is failing.

Then you can set a condition on your in your breakpoint, to watch only when the boolean is set to true.

In IntelliJ, you add your breakpoint as per normal, then right click on it, and select View Breakpoint. Another window open, and you can enter your condition.
Hope this helps.

Comment: From my point of view the same thing was advised earlier by @Harry Harrison.

Comment: No problem, we might have been typing at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- You can like you said use an conditional breakpoint if there is some state (value) in the common code, that is specific to the test you are trying to check. For example a specific string parameter.
- You can put an **extra** breakpoint in the test you are trying to check
  before the common code is called from this test. Once this breakpoint
  is hit you activate the **original** breakpoint. You can do this
  manually or using the option "*Disabled until selected breakpoint is
  hit*" in the breakpoint dialog of the **original** breakpoint by
  choosing your **extra** breakpoint in the combo box. If you use the
  "automatic"-way you can even uncheck "*Suspend*" for the **extra**
  breakpoint. This way it will only halt/suspend on your **original** breakpoint.